# Add custom icon and label in google map

Tags: android, google-maps

Image below is from Google Maps. Can we do similar things in our Android app? I believe those are not markers, instead it's an icon and label.

[image: screenshot taken from google map]

Some even have a snippet/subtitle under the label, like the `Top Rated` under the label. I don't know what keyword to search to find a way to do this in our own app.
[image: screenshot taken from google map]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible. You need to:

1. Remove all "default" places labels from map like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49090477/6950238) answer of [josef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4239860/jozef):

> a) create JSON file src\main\res\raw\map_style.json like this:
>
> ```
> [
>   {
>     featureType: "poi",
>     elementType: "labels",
>     stylers: [
>       {
>         visibility: "off"
>       }
>     ]
>   }
> ]
> ```
>
> b) add map style to your GoogleMap:
>
> ```
> `googleMap.setMapStyle(MapStyleOptions.loadRawResourceStyle(getContext(), R.raw.map_style));`
> ```

2. Get information about places "manually" via [Places SDK for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/overview) and parse information about each place. For example, you need get [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/android-sdk/place-details) for each place and analyze `Place.Field.RATING` and `Place.Field.USER_RATINGS_TOTAL` to determine "top rated" places. And don't forget to enable Places API for your application.
3. Create custom marker with text like in answers for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17837510/6950238) question. Or draw whatever you need directly on `MapView` (or `MapFragment`) canvas via creating custom view that extends `MapView` (or `MapFragment`) like in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54651717/6950238) answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I will go with one of the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58177393/301584 from one of the link you gave above!

Comment: @imin You're welcome!